# User authentication PHP mySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, xampp

So I am currently building a user authentication system using php and mysql in Xampp.

I have managed to get it to recognize if a user exists by their email address, but the other functions don't seem to be working. For example to check if the user has activated their account or not comes back as they haven't even if I change their active status to 1 in the database. Or with the login function even if both email and password are correct it will say that they are incorrect.

Here is my login.php script

```
    <?php
include 'init.php';


function sanitize($data){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

//check if user exists
function user_exists($email){
        $email = sanitize($email);
        //$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('ID') FROM 'register' WHERE 'email' = '$email'");
        return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM register WHERE email = '$email'"),0) == 1)? true : false;
}

//check if user has activated account
function user_activate($email){
        $email = sanitize($email);
        //$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('ID') FROM 'register' WHERE 'email' = '$email'");
        return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND 'active' =1"),0) == 1)? true : false;
}
function user_id_from_email($email){
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM register WHERE email = '$email'"),0,'id'));
}
function login($email,$password){
    $user_id = user_id_from_email($email);
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND 'password' ='$password'"),0) == 1)? $user_id : false;
}


if(empty($_POST)=== false){
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

if(empty($email)|| empty($password) === true){
        $errors[] = "You must enter a username and a password"; 
}
else if(user_exists($email) === false){
    $errors[] = "Email address is not registered";  
}
else if(user_activate($email) === false){
    $errors[] = "You haven't activated your account yet";   
}
else{
    $login = login($email, $password);
    if($login === false){
        $errors[] = "email/password are incorrect";
    } else {
        echo "ok";
    }
}

print_r($errors);


/*$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


if($email&&$password){
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Couldn't Connect");
    mysql_select_db("users") or die("Couldn't find Database");
}
    else 
        die("Please enter a username and a password");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '$email'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo $numrows;*/


?>
```

My database is called `'users'` and at the moment only has 1 table called `'register'`. With the rows: `id, firstname, lastname, email, password, and active`.

Comment: Bad programming!!! Why query database 4 times for same table, same user, same session? Query once and get the data into variables and then compare the values in php instead of querying database for all values separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your function login, try to remove the quotes ' arround the field name password. Or prefer use this one ` .

And take care, you are using function mysql_result and mysql_query that both are no longer supported in PHP 7.0

As you can see here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: The same applies to the field active. You are using quotes which makes the expression to check if the word "active" equals 1.  This is always false.